# A pythonic and uFunc-y way to turn pandas column into "increasing" index?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas df like so:

```
Index   A     B
0      foo    3
1      foo    2
2      foo    5
3      bar    3
4      bar    4
5      baz    5
```

What's a good fast way to add a column like so:

```
Index   A     B    Aidx
0      foo    3    0
1      foo    2    0
2      foo    5    0
3      bar    3    1
4      bar    4    1
5      baz    5    2
```

I.e. adding an increasing index for each unique value?

I know I could use `df.unique()`, then use a dict and `enumerate` to create a lookup, and then apply that dictionary lookup to create the column. But I feel like there should be faster way, possibly involving `groupby` with some special function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No need `groupby` using

---

Method 1`factorize`

```
pd.factorize(df.A)[0]
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
#df['Aidx']=pd.factorize(df.A)[0]
```

---

Method 2 sklearn

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(df.A)
LabelEncoder()
le.transform(df.A)
array([2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1])
```

---

Method 3 `cat.codes`

```
df.A.astype('category').cat.codes
```

---

Method 4 `map` + `unique`

```
l=df.A.unique()
df.A.map(dict(zip(l,range(len(l)))))
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

---

Method 5 `np.unique`

```
x,y=np.unique(df.A.values,return_inverse=True)
y
array([2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

EDIT: Some timings with OP's dataframe

'''

```
%timeit pd.factorize(view.Company)[0]

The slowest run took 6.68 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 155 µs per loop

%timeit view.Company.astype('category').cat.codes

The slowest run took 4.48 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000 loops, best of 3: 449 µs per loop

from itertools import izip

%timeit l = view.Company.unique(); view.Company.map(dict(izip(l,xrange(len(l)))))

1000 loops, best of 3: 666 µs per loop

import numpy as np

%timeit np.unique(view.Company.values, return_inverse=True)

The slowest run took 8.08 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.7 µs per loop
```

Seems like numpy wins.

Comment: Good solutions, they should be really fast as well. May be add time comparison as OP is looking for the most efficient solution

Comment: @Vaishali sorry it is hard for me to get the timing , would you mind add that for me , thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

One way is to use [`ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html). Just remember you have to make sure your groupby isn't resorting the groups to get your desired output, so set `sort=False`:

```
df['Aidx'] = df.groupby('A',sort=False).ngroup()
>>> df
   Index    A  B  Aidx
0      0  foo  3     0
1      1  foo  2     0
2      2  foo  5     0
3      3  bar  3     1
4      4  bar  4     1
5      5  baz  5     2
```

Answer (score 5):

One more method of doing so could be.

```
df['C'] = i.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum()-1
df
```

When we print `df` value it will be as follows.

```
  Index  A    B  C
0  0     foo  3  0
1  1     foo  2  0 
2  2     foo  5  0 
3  3     bar  3  1 
4  4     bar  4  1 
5  5     baz  5  2
```

***Explanation of solution:*** Let's break above solution into parts for understanding purposes.

***1st step:*** Compare df's A column by shifting its value down to itself as follows.

```
i.ne(df.A.shift())
```

Output we will get is:

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5     True
```

***2nd step:*** Use of `cumsum()` function, so wherever TRUE value is coming(which will come when a match of A column and its shift is NOT found) it will call `cumsum()` function and its value will be increased.

```
i.ne(df.A.shift()).cumsum()-1
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    2
Name: A, dtype: int32
```

***3rd step:*** Save command's value into `df['C']` which will create a new column named `C` in `df`.

Comment: Nice method ve++ for you